# How to access List from Sub Site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a Site Named *Application Test*. In this site i again Create a Sub site Named *Sub Application*.

I add in site url `"http://SP2010:2222/"` in Visual Studio Project
Project Scope is Site.
Now i when i try to access the List ( *TestList* ) From Sub site ( *Sub Application* ) it give error List Does not Exist.
Following Code to Access the List( *TestList* ):

```
using (SPSite sites = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = sites.OpenWeb())
            {
              SPList CurrentList = web.Lists["TestList"]; // Error comes here
            }
        }
```

anybody have solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
using (SPSite sites = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
 {
    using (SPWeb web = sites.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPWebCollection subsites= web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(); //get subsites
           for (int i= 0; i< subsites.Count; i++)
              {
                SPWeb subSiteWeb= subsites[i];

                   SPList CurrentList = subSiteWeb.Lists["TestList"];
                   if (CurrentList != null)
                   break;       
               }                  
        }
 }
```

Comment: which would work, but which you shouldn't do. Imagine there are 500 subwebs :-)

Comment: In that case you will have to specify the url of the subsite while creating instance of the SPSite.

Comment: Its working but i don't have specific url. This page is redirected from command action

Comment: @Vikalp [its work if i create subsite for subsite?] what do you mean by this?

Comment: it mean if hierarchy is like this then its work?  "http://SP2010:2222/Application/Sub_Application/SubSite"

Comment: @Vikalp, make SPWebCollection subsites= web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(); recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Well `SPContext.Current.Site` is the current site you deployed your *thing* to - whatever it is. But when you do `sites.OpenWeb()` without any parameters is opens the `RootWeb` and if the root web doesn't have your list you won't find it there.

Try to open the web and the site explicitly by using their respective URLs e.g. `http://SP2010:2222/`